# Getting error "could not execute native bulk manipulation query" while executing SQL statement using CreateSQLQuery() in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

```
private static void ExecuteSampleDDLCommands(ISession session)
{
    // Write the sql
    string ddlCommands=" begin 
            if exists(select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'test_bus_bkp') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1) 
            begin 
              insert into test_bus_bkp (c_Bus_Id, c_UID, c_BusName, c_BusLocation) 
                  select c_Bus_Id, c_UID, c_BusName, c_BusLocation from test_bus
              Delete from test_bus
              insert into test_bus (c_Bus_Id,c_UID, c_BusName, c_BusLocation) 
              select c_Bus_Id,c_UID, c_BusName, c_BusLocation from test_bus_bkp
            end; 
            else 
            begin 
             select * into test_bus_bkp from test_bus
             Delete from test_bus
             insert into test_bus (c_Bus_Id, c_UID, c_BusName, c_BusLocation) 
             select c_Bus_Id, c_UID, c_BusName, c_BusLocation from t_bus_bkp
             end; 
          end;";

    IQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery(ddlCommands);
    query.ExecuteUpdate();

}
```

I am trying to implement an `if exists,insert,delete` data access method in `NHibernate`. My database is Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

I am getting error when try to run this code through C# :

> could not execute native bulk manipulation query

Why I am getting this error?

Comment: I think you get the error when you don't have `test_bus_bkp` table in your database, and If yes try to use a `CREATE TABLE` command instead of `SELECT * INTO ...` ;).

Comment: @ hi shA.t , even if the table  test_bus_bkp exists then also it does not execute the insert into test_bus_bkp... statement

Comment: Well, I suggest you to store your script in a Stored Procedure then just call that, Or if it's valid use `.ExecuteNonQuery()` ;).

Comment: please let me know what wrong's in the query mentioned above in question and why it is not possible to execute CreateSqlQuery() for the  multiple statements ?

Comment: I think your script is correct when you run it in the SSMS, So I thought that it could come from new lines, that I could suggest you to add an `@` before your script, although you don't need the first `begin` and `end;` in the script, So as an optimization I prefer to use SP whit using `ExecuteNonQuery()` ;).